# SQL/Presto: rank with multiple conditions (one condition is checking if rows is in the same tag)

Tags: sql, database, presto

I have a data (dt) like the following:

```
  group_id    customer_id  tag     score   phase
  1           a             l1     0       2020
  1           b             l2     0       2021
  2           a             l4     1       2019
  2           e             l3     1       2019
  2           d             l3     1       2018
  3           q                    1       2020
  3           w                    1       2019
  3           z             l5     1       2019
  3           x             l5     1       2019
  3           c             l6     1       2019
```

I want to

1. rank them within a group, first by score (lower score is better)
2. then concat customer_id if the 2 customers are in the same group with the same score, and same tag (NOT null)
3. I need to rank them by phase (older phase is preferred) to produce a final list.

So, the desired output is:

```
 group_id    customer_id   tag     score     phase          rank
  1           a             l1     0         2020           1    
  1           b             l2     0         2021           2
  2           a             l4     1         2019           2
  2           e,d           l3     1        2019, 2018      1
  3           q                    1         2020           2
  3           w                    1         2019           1
  3           z,x           l5     1       2019, 2019       1
  3           c             l6     1       2019             1
```

I have written the following query but I am not sure how to incorporate the condition of checking if 2 customers are in the tag and proceed further to add phase comparing condition.

```
  SELECT group_id, customer_id, tag, score, phase, 
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY score) AS temp_rank
  FROM dt
```

Comment: concating e and d since they are in the same group and have the same tags. changed the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must `group by group_id, tag, score` and use `array_join(array_agg())` to concatenate `customer_id`s and `phase`s for the rows with non-NULL tag.
Then use `UNION ALL` for the rows with NULL tag.
Then use instead of `RANK()` use `DENSE_RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT group_id, customer_id, tag, score, phase,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY score, min_phase) temp_rank
FROM (
  SELECT group_id, 
         array_join(array_agg(customer_id), ',') customer_id, 
         tag, 
         score, 
         array_join(array_agg(phase), ',') phase,
         MIN(phase) min_phase
  FROM dt
  WHERE tag IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY group_id, tag, score
  UNION ALL
  SELECT group_id, customer_id, tag, score, phase, phase
  FROM dt
  WHERE tag IS NULL
) t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3fef8e96c5f85b6d97a2a0dba30ef4f0) (for Postgresql).
Results:

| group_id | customer_id | tag | score | phase | temp_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | l1 | 0 | 2020 | 1 |
| 1 | b | l2 | 0 | 2021 | 2 |
| 2 | e,d | l3 | 1 | 2019,2018 | 1 |
| 2 | a | l4 | 1 | 2019 | 2 |
| 3 | w | null | 1 | 2019 | 1 |
| 3 | c | l6 | 1 | 2019 | 1 |
| 3 | z,x | l5 | 1 | 2019,2019 | 1 |
| 3 | q | null | 1 | 2020 | 2 |

Comment: what will this query do to those rows without tags?

Comment: @lll `GROUP BY group_id, tag, score` creates unique combinations of the 3 columns. A combination may have `null` as tag.

Comment: i want only for the cases to concate when the tags are not null. when i tried the queries just now, if tags are null, they are concatenated

Comment: @lll post sample data with null tags to clarify what you want.

Comment: added a NULL tag case

Comment: @lll what if in group_id = 3 there are other rows with not null tags?

Comment: i updated the cases when group_id = 3 also have not null tags

Answer (score 0):

I used `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()`. The following query returns your desired output. I tested this query with sql. In a built-in subquery, I grouped by `tag` and put the same values in a column with the `STRING_AGG()` function. And I joined the result to the main table.

```
select t.group_id,t.customer_id,t.tag,t.score,t.phase,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.group_id ORDER BY t.score) AS rank
from
  (select distinct t1.*,t2.group_id,t2.score
  from
     (SELECT tag, STRING_AGG(customer_id, ',') AS customer_id,STRING_AGG(phase, ',') AS phase
      FROM dt
      group by tag) t1 join dt t2 on t1.tag = t2.tag) t
order by t.group_id,t.customer_id
```

result in sql : [https://dbfiddle.uk/sql](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d37554c2f0dd7711cc15925f51f8db71)

result in postgresql : [https://dbfiddle.uk/postgresql](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dd2ae55ce2b3853ba63b5208990b72ac)